# Android - Custom currency symbol

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I need a way to display custom currency symbol. I'm using NumberFormat and I can't find a way to replace the currency symbol as it all depends on the locale. the symbol I want to use for currency is a specific symbol for the app I'm working on. any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put symbols directly into your format pattern and surround them with apostrophes (just in case they are a pattern symbol) instead of using the currency symbol notation.

```
fun main() {
    val input = 5.47
    val symbol = '\u263a'
    val result = DecimalFormat("'$symbol'#.##").format(input)
    println(result)
}
```